# Jquery click alert()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Do you know why this method click doesn't show alert? Because I'm not able to catch this event.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery(".jtable-command-button.jtable-edit-command-button").click(function () {
        alert("asdas");
    });
});

</script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>My First JavaScript</h1>
<p id="demo">This is a paragraph.</p>

<button class="jtable-command-button jtable-edit-command-button" title="Edytuj pozycję">

</body>
</html>
```

I give you for all of you points for help [closed] thanks

Comment: Two reasons: Wrong selector and not executed at the right time. Please read the [tutorial](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery): *"As almost everything we do when using jQuery reads or manipulates the document object model (DOM), we need to make sure that we start adding events etc. as soon as the DOM is ready. To do this, we register a ready event for the document."*.

Comment: Have you included `jQuery` in the page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You are trying to use a `$` function (probably from jQuery) without defining it (e.g. by loading jQuery)
2. You are trying to find the event handler before the element you are binding to has been created
3. You are using an `id` selector but the element doesn't have an id (it does have a class) (**Note: after the first edit of the question, this is no longer the case**)
4. You are using a `descendant combinator` and a `type selector`, but the `type` should be a `class` and the element you are targeting belongs to both classes. It doesn't have an ancestor element which is a member of either of the classes. (Note: The HTML class attribute takes a *space separated list* of classes)
5. The end tag and label for the button are missing

A fixed version of the JS part would be:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script> <!-- Set this path correctly -->
<script>
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery(".jtable-command-button.jtable-edit-command-button").click(function () {
        alert("asdas");
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".jtable-command-button.jtable-edit-command-button").click(function () {
alert("asdas");
```

You need to include the '`.`' after `.jtable-command-button` as `jtable-edit-command-button` is a class.

Comment: @Rafael-JuniorMVCDeveloper — You have 5 different problems, this answer only fixes one of them.

Comment: @Quentins answer has now been updated and you should use that.

Comment: I check - is not working. http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_events

Comment: @saji89 this was an original error in the OP's code which I didnt spot AND now has been updated. Read quentins answer for the run down.

Comment: @CecilTheodore, No problem.. I see that you have updated your answer now. :)

Answer (score 2):

You have class name, so class selecter starts with `.` in jquery.

```
$(".jtable-command-button.jtable-edit-command-button").click(function () {
    alert("asdas");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

you should use . for class and # for id

```
$(".jtable-command-button").click(function () {
   alert("asdas");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope you have jQuery declared? If so, try this:

```
$(".jtable-command-button.jtable-edit-command-button").click(function () {
   alert("asdas");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As per your code you have used # for call click event function But # is use for ID and dot (.) is used for class so you have used .(dot) instead of #

```
 $(".jtable-command-button.jtable-edit-command-button").click(function () {
    alert("asdas");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've downloaded jquery you have to import the js file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="yourPath/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>  //your jquery version
```

Then you can try as above answers or:

```
$("button[title='Edytuj pozycję']").click(function(){
alert("asdad");
});
```